# How to update a particular column on behalf of id in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update Flag column in sqlite table from 0 to 1 so when the data is send to server the flag update from 0 to 1. Here is my code :

Create table Code :

```
db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + Order_Master + " ( " + KEY_Order_No + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + KEY_Order_Date + " DATE , " + KEY_Member_Code + " VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL , " + KEY_Table_No + " VARCHAR(100) , " +
                  KEY_WAITER_NAME + " VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL , " + KEY_HH_CODE + " VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL ," + KEY_CHILD_NAME + " VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL , " + KEY_CHILD_STATUS + " VARCHAR (2) NOT NULL , "
                  + KEY_SALES_TYPE + " VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL , " +  KEY_AMOUNT + " VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL , " + KEY_FLAG + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL ) ; ");
```

Insert into table code :

```
public boolean insertMaster  (ContentValues contentValues)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.insert("Order_Master", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }
```

now I need to update the last column "flag" from 0 to 1. Can any one help me how can I create the update method?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set `KEY_order_no` as primary key you can use that to identify the row to update as below

```
db.update("Order_Master", contentValues,
      KEY_order_no + "='" + key_order_no + "'", null)
```

Comment: i have used this method but my database didn't update...can u please tell me what's that problem?

Comment: post the code and error you got while using the above method to update

Comment: String flag="1"

and my i called my update method like this

                            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                            contentValues.put("Order_No ", orderNo);
                            contentValues.put("Order_Date", formattedDate);
                          
                            contentValues.put("FLAG" , flag.toString());
                            a.updatemaster(contentValues);

Comment: my database didn't update can you please tell me..it would be great full

Answer (score 0):

use this method to update value

public void updateStatus(String id , int status){

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues data = new ContentValues();

data.put("status", status);

db.update(TableName, data, "columnName" + " = "+id , null);

}